# Integrating jitsi in java-fx

Tags: javafx-8, jitsi

I am developing an video calling application using javafx. And I need to integrate jitsi video   GUI into javafx Swing node.

Is it possible or Do I have to use 'libjitsi' and implement GUI in javafx ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it mean you have a working jitsi client in java and you just need the GUI in javafx? But the plan is to use it in a swing application?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to embed Swing content into JavaFX, you can use a `SwingNode`.
It worked for me (I added a Swing PDF player in a JavaFX application)

Here is an example of how to perform this : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm

Answer (score 0):

This might be very late but still, I am posting the answer as seems to be a genuine question.

To use JavaFX with jitsi, developing with eclipse steps are as follows.

1. First, you require to install an addon of JavaFX in eclipse e. g. [EFX](http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/)
2. After adding above addon add JavaFX SDK to the project. The link: https://www.tutorialkart.com/javafx/install-javafx-in-eclipse-ide/
3. Then add the **package entries** to the **manifest.mf** files {in the package where you are executing} and **felix.run.properties** file.

And the project will run smoothly. Another thing if using a class with the superclass of Application then keep it in the different jar file add the entries of the jar to the build.xml(in copy jar section) and add the **package entries** to the **manifest.mf** files {in the package where you are executing} and **felix.run.properties** file.